# Arrow function vs Component React

Tags: reactjs, performance, rendering

I recently made a pull request at my company and got feedback on some code that I had written and I wanted some other opinions on this.
We have an component called `Icon` that can take another component as a prop like so:

`<Icon component={ArrowDown}/>`

this simply renders the following:

```
<IconContainer>
    <ArrowDown/>
</IconContainer>
```

Now you can also do the follow if you need to create a custom icon:

`<Icon component={()=><div>custom Icon</div>}/>`

The reviewer commented that the function `()=><div>custom Icon</div>` should be removed outside the scope for performance reasons to prevent re-rendering:

```
const CustomIcon = ()=><div>custom Icon</div>
const someComponent = ()=><Icon component={customIcon}/>
```

I'm not convinced that this will improve performance (code-readability sure) but wanted to get some other opinions on it.
Thanks!

Comment: I believe the `component` prop is re-created on every render, which causes the `Ìcon` to re-render. But I'm not sure that would affect the performance. Because simply it is a small component and not a layout with so many nested divs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrow functions are `anonymous` and will be re-instantiated on every render.

If you create a named component, it will have a reference and will not be re-rendered by React unless and until required (through state update).

And also, as you mentioned, it provides better `readability` and an option for `code splitting`.